# Windows 8 double download

Tags: windows-8

I recently cleaned my hard drive on my HP Pavilion 20 All-In-One PC and restarted it back like it was new. Then i get a pop up from Norton Internet Security, stating that file svchost.exe basically is holding alot of memory. So when i did a search in my c: drive, it looked to be some of the files are duplicated for Windows 8. How can i find out if these are duplicated files and delete them safely, without having to clean my hard drive again.

Comment: why do you think they are duplicated? Please give examples or screenshot.  I use Norton, so don't take this the wrong way, but NIS complaining that svchost.exe is using a lot of memory is only a warning.  If you get that warning ALOT then worry about it, if it pops up once then just ignore it.  Also a complete reboot would be a good first step to see if svchost is misbehaving or just happened to be using more mem than NIS figured it should be.

Comment: Yes, it was a warning about svchost.exe. is using a lot of memory. It came up a few times about 2 days. Then I stated to research Windows 8 double download & really have not seen it since the 1st day. So u think I shouldn't worry about & just leave it alone.

Comment: answered that in an answer =]

Comment: If you are searching for a particular system file anywhere within `C:`, you will find many duplicate file names. But these files are not necessarily duplicates, and the OS *does* need them. For example, one might be a 32-bit version, and the other a 64-bit version. One might be a backup used by Windows Resource Protection (in case your main system files get corrupted). One might be part of a Windows Update, which sticks around in case you need to roll back the update. Don't try to be too clever: Windows is doing the right thing on its own. Leave it alone and it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

Svshost is an executable that runs logical groupings of windows services. 
It's possible that a service can use more memory than normal, thus Norton's warning.  Norton typically doesn't notify the user as soon as there is high usage, but rather when it seems too much of the total is being consumed over a period of time.  THe state at which your computer becomes sluggish.

That brings us to the question of balance. Should Norton be WARNING you for the levels/durations it's seeing?  Or on the other hand, does Norton's tolerances need to be set so that you occasionally see Norton's presence?  After all when it's time to pay for Norton again you will feel much better if Norton's telling you something from time to time.  You know it's there, you know it's working. That renewal fee seems so much more worthwhile than it would if Norton never told you anything. They could make it do it's job, mostly silently, but when renewal time rolled around, you might say "wait what has Norton really done for me?"


So to answer your specific question in the comment attached to the original question, If you see THE WARNING once a day or once a week then just ignore it (and get that happy feeling Norton wants you to have because you know it's there working for you).  On the other hand, if your getting it multiple time an hour and your PC is sluggish, now you have a place to start.